# PHP: Add translated tags to category list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website made from a template in Wordpress, I've installed a translation plugin (qtranslate).

http://madebysylvie.be/collection

In my "photo album" page when I sort the items in the default language (english) everything works fine, however if I change to another translation (ex.french), the name of the category changes and the tagged items don't appear anymore.

Here is the PHP code that executes that function,

```
<ul class="filter_portfolio"> 

                <?php
                    // Get the taxonomy


                    $terms = get_terms('filter', $args);
                    // set a count to the amount of categories in our taxonomy
                    $count = count($terms); 
                    // set a count value to 0
                    $i=0;
                    // test if the count has any categories
                    if ($count > 0) {
                        // break each of the categories into individual elements
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            // increase the count by 1
                            $i++;


                            // rewrite the output for each category

                            $term_list .= '<li class="segment-'.$i.'"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';


                            // if count is equal to i then output blank
                            if ($count != $i)
                            {
                                $term_list .= '';
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                $term_list .= '';
                            }
                        }
                        // print out each of the categories in our new format
                        echo $term_list;

                    }
                ?>

            </ul>
```

I would like to change this block of code in order to identify the tags in the translated version. I know that the trigger is the ("data-value") parameter.

The following code let's me translate the taxonomies from the default language,

```
function qtranslate_edit_taxonomies(){
$args=array(
  'public' => true ,
  '_builtin' => false
);
$output = 'object'; // or objects
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

$taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 

if  ($taxonomies) {
 foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
     add_action( $taxonomy->name.'_add_form', 'qtrans_modifyTermFormFor');
     add_action( $taxonomy->name.'_edit_form', 'qtrans_modifyTermFormFor');        

 }
 }

}
add_action('admin_init', 'qtranslate_edit_taxonomies');
?>
```

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Can you give the `get_terms()` function code ? It seems like it's this function that create the list of items you want, and where the translate adjustment has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect you use the category name to filter your database records. So in your db there is only the "englsh" name and when you "translate" it your script is unable to work properly since it uses the new "french" name.

Can you try to convert the category name to engish before executing your query?



**EDIT**
What i actually think is for you to find a way to pass two variables to your php script. Whatever suits your needs.
For example, some possible scenarios are:
- category in english + language (fr) = based on your selected language you query your db and return proper results(based on english work thought)
- category id + language (fr) = same as above but more generic since you use an id to get data from table.

I am guessing you must change somewhat your html and you php script (one to pass correct data and the other to return correct format).

Comment: Yes if I change the category name to be the same in every translation it works, The script is getting the "name" and not the "slug". The slug is the same in all translations.

Comment: @Dles its worth trying this out.

Comment: I am trully sorry but I don´t think I am following, I converted the category name in every translation to english. Is that what you mean?

Comment: could you tell me which function should I use to query my database?
I searched the PHP manual and I found the "Mysqli" extension. but I could not find the proper one for this case. thanks